# ¿Cómo creo un diagrama Entidad Relación usando plantuml?

Tags: plantuml, diagrama-er

¿Existe alguna forma de crear un diagrama ER usando plant UML?

Busqué en la documentación del [sitio oficial](http://plantuml.com/) y no hallé nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible, al parecer sigue siendo una opción no documentada, la única fuente parece ser el [ejemplo de código de QuantumGhost](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hvmtxnb11ccJ:https://gist.github.com/QuantumGhost/0955a45383a0b6c0bc24f9654b3cb561%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=mx).

Deberás iniciar con la plantilla que se indica en ese gist, que actualmente es algo así:

```
@startuml
' descomentar si se tiene un display retina
' skinparam dpi 300
!define Table(name,desc) class name as "desc" << (T,#FFAAAA) >>
' negrita para llave primaria
' color verde para restricciones únicas
' subrayado para campos no nulos
!define primary_key(x) <b>x</b>
!define unique(x) <color:green>x</color>
!define not_null(x) <u>x</u>
' otras etiquetas disponibles:
' <i></i>
' <back:COLOR></color>, donde color es el nombre de un color o su código html
' (#FFAACC)
' vea: http://plantuml.com/classes.html#More
hide methods
hide stereotypes

' entities

' relationships

@enduml
```

Las entidades se agregan así:

```
Table(empleado, "Empleado\n(Usuario del sistema)") {
primary_key(id) INTEGER
not_null(unique(usuario)) VARCHAR[32]
not_null(password) VARCHAR[64]
}
```

Puedes revisar el ejemplo que postea en el enlace para ver más de notación.